# Insert query fails with error duplicate entry , where as select query returns null

Tags: mysql, duplicates

Insert query fails with error  "Duplicate entry"
But when I try to run SELECT query for the primary key , it returns no rows .

If there are no rows present , then how come can this be duplicate entry

Desc MyTable;

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
folderId    binary(16)  NO  PRI     
referenceId binary(16)  NO  PRI     
referenceType   String  NO
```

Insert Query

```
Select folderId_2 from FolderRecordContents limit 5;
INSERT INTO MyTable
SET folderid = 'value1',
    referenceid = 'value 11',
    referenceType = 'value 111';
```

This fails with error "`Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '\xA7\xC0\xF0\xCF\x06\xDDN0\xB7\x9F\xC8bc\x96\xE3\xF7-TestSchema-' for key 'folderId_2'`"

So I Try to see if there is any entry 
Select Query

```
Select * from MyTable 
Where folderId = 'value1' and 
      referenceid = 'value 11';
```

Result : `"No rows returned"`

I don't understand 2 things

1. If there is no output for select, then how is duplication happening here?
2. Duplication error says for key 'folderId_2' but the column name is 'folderid' not 'folderId_2'

UPDATE:

I searched for the indexes on the table , 
Turns out , there is a index created for the table with name 'folderId_2'

now how can I avoid duplication with index .

Comment: Do you have any triggers defined for this table?

Comment: Pls run query `Select * from MyTable Where folderId = 'value1'` exclude `referenceid = 'value 11'`

Comment: yes tried that as well , no rows

Comment: @peterm : I found an index created for the tble with name 'folderId_2' , I dont understand how I can manage to get past it now , Should I try to fetch all keys in index or something ?

Comment: @RyanNghiem : updated the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If there is no output for select, then how is duplication happening here. In a  select if a value in a column null then use the default value. The second null row produces a duplicated value
2. Duplication error says for key `folderId_2` but the column name is `folderid` not `folderId_2`. `folderId_2` is the name of an index ..  probably you have create a unique constraints on column `folderId` with name `folderId_2`

   For this you should remove the unique constraints dropping and recreate the index  without unique clause